# msvcr120d Is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I've been trying to compile on opencv program in C++ and I have randomly started getting this error message.

[image: MSError]

Using dependency walker I can see that this dll is needed by my program but is net being found.

I used Xsearch to search my computer for the dll but it is not found.

I have downloaded a copies of the dlls (both the release and debgu versions) and placed them in the same directory as my application.

I have also tried placing them in the C:\windows\System32 folder and using regsvr32 to register them.

Regsvr32 gives me another error message

[image: Regsvr32]

I've also tried installing the [redistributable packages](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) for visual studio with no effect.

I seem to be running out of options :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doh

Figured it out

Was using msvcr120 instead of msvcp120